# How can I insert ternary operation in 4th parameter in form_dropdown function in codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I want my javascript onchange function not to be called whenever my `$at_row[0]->ID` is true. The javascript onchange function call was placed in my form_dropdown function. I have tried my code but it wasn't working at all and prompts errors. How could I do this right? Here is my code.

Working code

```
 <?php echo form_dropdown('at[brgy1]',$dropdown_brgy1,(isset($at_row[0]->ID)) ? $at_row[0]->brgy1 : '',"id=brgy_id_1 class=form-control style=width:300px  onchange=javascript:change_barangay_2(); "); ?>
```

Not working code

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('at[brgy1]',$dropdown_brgy1,(isset($at_row[0]->ID)) ? $at_row[0]->brgy1 : '',"id=brgy_id_1 class=form-control style=width:300px  "(isset($at_row[0]->ID)) ? return false : "onchange=javascript:change_barangay_2()";"    "); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using ternary operator wrongly, the `return false` doesn't make any sense the current context, you just have to put empty string `""` instead so that if condition expression is true, nothing will be appended to the string.

here is the statement that should work.

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('at[brgy1]',$dropdown_brgy1,(isset($at_row[0]->ID)) ? $at_row[0]->brgy1 : '',"id=brgy_id_1 class=form-control style=width:300px  "(isset($at_row[0]->ID)) ? "" : "onchange=javascript:change_barangay_2();"); ?>
```